# EXTJS Combobox : show only NONselected values in dropdownlist for each combo-selection

Tags: extjs3

i have an  combobox in a gridcolumn and the requirment is to show only nonselected values in the dropdown list for the next combo selection

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use the [superselectbox](http://technomedia.co.uk/SuperBoxSelect/examples3.html). If you want to customize the standard combobox, you can take a look at the superselectbox source code - it is actually extended combobox.